# How to add password field to VS Code Settings page?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on my first VS Code extension. Below code is what I come up with to accept user level credentials that needs to be stored.

I was unable to find how to include a "password text box" in to the settings page, and also need to know what is the best approach to store them securely in the disk.

My questions are:

Is it possible to add a password box in the settings page?
What should be the best approach to save credentials securely (encrypted) in the extension data storage? Is there an API for this?

```
    "configuration": [
        {
            "type":"object",
            "title": "MySettings",
            "properties": {
                "conf.myExt.Uid": {
                    "$id": "txtUser",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": null,
                    "markdownDescription": "UserName",
                    "scope": "window"
                },
                "conf.myExt.Secret": {
                    "$id": "txtPassword",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": null,
                    "markdownDescription": "Password",
                    "scope": "window"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Did you ever find a good answer to this? It seems like some extensions aren't bothering to worry about security. I've been looking to contribute to some of the ones I use that don't handle passwords as securely as I'd prefer.